# BoxSizer issue: Not expanding to fit contents of StaticText

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm creating a StaticText element with multiple child StaticText elements that aren't quite sizing correctly. I'm sure it's a BoxSizer issue, but maybe not? Here's a screenshot of what's happening: http://cloud.smallparade.com/CMxC

That should read:

```
Wilco
One Sunday Morning (Song
For Jane Smiley's Boyfriend)
The Whole Love (Deluxe Edition)
```

As you can likely deduce, the second and third lines (Album) are one StaticText element that's wrapping but not expanding to fit its contents.

Here is the code that creates this element:

```
def PlayLabel(self, artist, track, album):
    header_font = wx.Font(26, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, False, "Helvetica")
    album_font = wx.Font(18, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, False, "Helvetica")

    # label container
    block = wx.StaticText(self.Sidebar, -1, '')

    block.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    block.SetBackgroundColour('WHITE')

    label_artist = wx.StaticText(block, -1, artist)
    label_artist.SetForegroundColour('BLACK')
    label_artist.SetFont(header_font)

    label_track = wx.StaticText(block, -1, track)
    label_track.SetForegroundColour('BLACK')
    label_track.SetFont(header_font)

    label_album = wx.StaticText(block, -1, album)
    label_album.SetForegroundColour('BLACK')
    label_album.SetFont(album_font)

    block.sizer.AddMany([
        (label_artist, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 5),
        (label_track, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 5),
        (label_album, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, 5)
    ])
    block.SetSizerAndFit(block.sizer)

    self.Sidebar.sizer.Add(block, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.BOTTOM, 5)
    self.Sidebar.sizer.Layout()
    self.Layout()
    return block
```

Any idea what's going on?

**EDIT:**

Complete code: http://pastie.org/2976327

Comment: this sounds like a very heterodox sizer

Comment: Suggestions on making it orthodox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen anyone create a sizer like that. Normally you do this:

```
mySizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
```

Then you add each element. I suspect that since you're doing it in a weird way, you're getting weird results. Don't use the StaticText's sizer method for this. They are not container objects. Instead, do this:

```
block = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
```

And then add the other widgets as you did before. And telling the sizer to set itself won't work right either: "block.SetSizerAndFit(block.sizer)". You need to call the parent widget's SetSizer() method, which is probably the Sidebar here:

```
self.Sidebar.SetSizer(block)
```

or maybe you can just add it the way you had it here:

```
self.Sidebar.sizer.Add(block, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.BOTTOM, 5)
```

**EDIT**

Here's a simple code example:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test")

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        samples = [("Red", "Breathe Into Me", "End of Silence"),
                   ("eleventyseven", "Lonely", "Sugarfist"),
                   ("Lecrae", "Go Hard", "Rebel")]
        for sample in samples:
            artist, track, album = sample
            self.PlayLabel(artist, track, album)

        self.panel.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
        panelSizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        panelSizer.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(panelSizer)
        self.Fit()


    def PlayLabel(self, artist, track, album):
        header_font = wx.Font(26, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, False, "Helvetica")
        album_font = wx.Font(18, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, False, "Helvetica")

        block = self.panel

        # sizer
        sizer = self.mainSizer

        # artist
        label_artist = wx.StaticText(block, -1, artist)
        label_artist.SetForegroundColour('BLACK')
        label_artist.SetFont(header_font)

        # track
        label_track = wx.StaticText(block, -1, track)
        label_track.SetForegroundColour('BLACK')
        label_track.SetFont(header_font)

        # album
        label_album = wx.StaticText(block, -1, album)
        label_album.SetForegroundColour('BLACK')
        label_album.SetFont(album_font)

        sizer.AddMany([
                (label_artist, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 5),
                (label_track, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 5),
                (label_album, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 5)
        ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I personally don't like Fit() much, but in this case, it works for me.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding BoxSizer (which it seems a lot of people do). Do I need to create a new BoxSizer for every element with child elements? Here's the complete code in case it helps: http://pastie.org/2976327

Comment: I find that sketching your GUI out helps. Then you draw boxes around the widgets to decide which sizers you need. If you are going to stack two or more widgets vertically, use a BoxSizer to hold them. You need one sizer to hold them. The 3 main widgets that should have child elements are panels, frames and dialogs. Sizers are used to help organize the children.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I believe I followed your advice correctly but it's still not expanding the StaticText widgets that wrap: http://cloud.smallparade.com/COh8

Comment: Interesting. So is it generally best practice to create your sizers at the root level and use them throughout?

Comment: Not really. I just did that because you were creating a panel and a sizer every time and you didn't need to do that for this example. The panel can almost always hold all the widgets, but you might need to nest the sizers. There are several ways to approach this problem.